# Getting subarrays of JSON response using Mootools

Tags: multidimensional-array, mootools

Is there any altenative for Jquery $.map(array, function(item)) in mootools.

How can I change following JSON result

```
{"totalResultsCount":2,"geonames":[{"countryName":"India","name":"Cochin"},{"countryName":"Canada","name":"Cochin"},{"countryName":"Venezuela","name":"Cochina"}]}
```

as

```
[{"countryName":"India","name":"Cochin"},{"countryName":"Canada","name":"Cochin"},{"countryName":"Venezuela","name":"Cochina"}]
```

I need mootools alternate for  following jquery

```
    function(data) {
    response($.map(data.geonames, function(item) {


        return {
            label: item.name + (item.adminName1 ? ", " + item.adminName1 : "") + ", " + item.countryName,

        }

}))
```

Any help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

er, you should've probably read the mootools [documentation on Arrays](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Types/Array#Array%3amap) first. It is nearly identical, posting this just says 'I cannot be bothered to look it up'.

You can use the native Array type map method `Array.map(data.geonames, function(item) {})` - see http://jsfiddle.net/TD2rK/1/ - or call it via the prototype from `data.geonames.map(function(item) {})` - see http://jsfiddle.net/TD2rK/

`Array.map()` - method #1 - will be future proof with AMD and non-extended prototypes (think mootools 2.0 aka MILK).